# Can I walk out of Chicago Midway Airport (MDW)?

Tags: airports, chicago, mdw

Is it possible to walk out of MDW?

The reason I ask is because you can only schedule an UberBlack or UberSUV to pick you up from MDW. However, if I can walk to one of these spots just outside the airport:

- Dunkin' Donuts 4612 W 59th St, CTA Chicago, IL 60629
- Chill With Us Yogurt Cafe 4559 W 59th St Chicago, IL 60629
- Pasteur Park 5825 S Kostner Ave Chicago, IL 60629)

Uber could pick me up there and I save ~$30.

Comment: Where are you headed?  If possible, I recommend just taking the Orange Line.  You can transfer to any other trains downtown.

Comment: After googling a bit, it appears neither Dunkin' Donuts nor Chill With Us Yogurt Cafe are where Google Maps Says they are :/

Comment: @Brad That might be an option. I'd probably be heading directly to a friend's house. Either way I'm curious about leaving MDW on foot.

Comment: I was able to confirm this weekend that it is possible to walk out of MDW via the bus boarding area as @Carl [describes](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/43378/9861). However, the second part of my plan (having Uber pick me up there) was not quite so successful. In order for me to request an UberX, I would have to be 3-4 blocks away from MDW. Pasteur Park was roughly the nearest point I could drop the pin for an UberX. Ended up riding CTA.

Comment: Order an Uber cab to an area outside the airport, then call the driver and ask for an airport pickup. The geographical restriction is a legal trick, not a real limitation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Midway is very walkable, though there's a good bit of traffic so the surrounding areas aren't the nicest place to walk, but there are exits and sidewalks.

You might exit directly from the terminal onto Cicero, but there are few options where you could both wait comfortably in case of rain or snow or where a car could safely stop out of traffic.

A good option is to follow the signs to the CTA Station "Trains to City / Trains to Loop" (straight ahead as you exit the terminal, don't forget to go downstairs right after you exit the secure area to get your check luggage, if any).

At the Midway CTA station you can exit to the bus boarding area, you can cross it to [this parking lot (41.7852416,-87.7399196)](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.786184,-87.73938,3a,75y,92.09h,99.82t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sWVOcfu2mmqsZ9acLRhrVEQ!2e0) that doesn't have controlled access. This location is just down the street from the Chill With Us Yogurt Cafe but saves you having to cross the road.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I'll probably check this out and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Never been to Chicago Midway, but looking at satellite view on Google maps shows [access from the airport into the CTA Midway subway station](http://www.flychicago.com/m/midway/en/gettingtofrom/transportation/default.aspx#cta). The station is a couple hundred metres away from W59th street, and one of those cafes you mentioned seem to be just across the road from it:

[image: gmap screenshot]

So with my assumption being that if you can enter the subway station on foot you must also be able to exit it, I would say **it seems you can walk out of Chicago Midway Airport** to those Uber pickup spots.

Answer (score 0):

At Midway, walk to the CTA stop, then 
outside through the bus lanes onto 59th St.All Uber options show up there, address is 4618 W 59th. Maybe 50 yards 
farther than walking to the L.